# How to monitor a port bandwidth?

Tags: port, bandwidth, monitoring, network-traffic

How can I monitor a specific port's bandwidth?
I'm using squid cache server, and I want to find out how much bandwidth is preserved. using soft wares like DU METER it's not possible to measure that.
Is there any suggestion?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Testing bandwidth on a single port](http://superuser.com/questions/103772/testing-bandwidth-on-a-single-port)

Comment: Are you talking about TCP ports or physical Ethernet ports on a switch?

Comment: @grawity I mean TCP Ports, For example the port which a proxy is using.

Comment: @Excellll Is it duplicate because the words "port" and "bandwidth"? That's not even related!